# How to modify viscosity of ZnO ink?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, viscosity

I have stumbled upon [these instructions](https://ninithi.wordpress.com/2015/08/06/make-your-own-photocatalytic-zinc-oxide-nanoparticles-a-home-nanotech-project/) on how to create $\ce{ZnO}$ nanoparticles.

I am interested in making a DIY ink, for use with a parallel metal plate pen and a piezo-actuated microdrop nozzle.

My question is:

What is a reasonable way of controlling the viscosity of such an ink? Is it possible to replace the water with a mixture of water and isopropanol, for example?

Comment: Sure ink usually includes the following ingredients: petroleum distillate solvent, linseed oil, some form of organic pigments, and soybean oil.  If an ink has a linseed oil base, it will dry through air oxidation. When alcohol is present, the ink will dry through evaporation. Considering that I wonder if glycerol would be a good candidate for your dye?

Comment: Idea: As you have photoactive ZnO, mix it with clear aqueous (NH4)2SO4 (from MgSO4  + ammonia, remove white Mg(OH)2 precipitate). Then, use it as a finger paint (ink) to write on colored paper (best dark colors). Let dry. Place in strong sunlight after very litely spraying with a B12/water mix. Should reveal your written (with your finger) message as the moist chemicals bleach the dark paper.

Comment: How useful would white ink be ?

Comment: @Tartrate Printing electronics is of increasing interest.  Did you consider a publication like [2020Crystals449](https://doi.org/10.3390/cryst10060449) (open access) as an entry for further literature survey?

Answer (score 1):

Regular [black ink](https://wiki.anton-paar.com/en/ink/) is pretty viscous it has a dynamic viscosity ($\eta$) of 4.177.

In comparison a 50% mixture of methanol and glycerol has a viscosity of 5.8

Some other solvents to consider are

- Hexanol which has a viscosity of about 5.4
- Heptanol which has as viscosity of
  about 7.3

These long-chain alcohols, however, will not dissolve significantly in water.

Some more viscosity data can be found [here](https://www.usb.ac.ir/FileStaff/7785_2020-2-29-11-23-5.pdf) (it's not an ideal place for viscosities but it is free)

Linseed oil is also not water soluble. In any case here is another [link](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/30954/relation-between-temperature-and-viscosity-of-linseed-oil?rq=1)

Ultimately it seems like you'd need to try a few different mixtures to get desired viscosity, solubility and evaporation speed.